# Access variable in code-behind from Resources in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have the following problem:
I want to access one of these three vars, defined in XAML Resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Themes/MainStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <System:Int32 x:Key="maxVal">500</System:Int32>
        <System:Int32 x:Key="minVal">250</System:Int32>
        <System:Int32 x:Key="actualWidth">250</System:Int32>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I want to access the value of "actualWidth" from Codebehind file like this:

```
private void MinMaxGraphicsMessageSink(bool minmax)
{
   actualWidth = minmax ? 900 : 300;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int maxVal = (Convert.ToInt32(FindResource("maxVal")));`

similarly min value

`int minVal = (Convert.ToInt32(FindResource("minVal")));`

to set value of a resource you can do like this

```
var resourceDictionary = this.Resources;
resourceDictionary["actualWidth"] = somevalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
var max = (int)Application.Resources["maxValue"];
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
(int)this.FindResource("actualWidth")
```

Comment: thanks. But "This Expression cannot be used as an assignment target".